# Bitwise operation on enum which is not marked by [Flags] attribute

Tags: c#, enums, warnings, bitwise-operators

I am comparing a variable to many enum values, but the **IntelliSense** is giving me this warning:

[image: *Bitwise operation on enum which is not marked by [Flags] attribute.*]

```
if (val == MyEnum.Value1 | MyEnum.Value2 | MyEnum.Value3){
   //code
}
```

My enum looks like this:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("Value1")]
    Value1 = 0,
    [Description("Value2")]
    Value2 = 1,
    [Description("Value3")]
    Value3 = 2,
}
```

What is it and what should I do? Is it safe? All i want to avoid is having to write the long version of an if multi-value comparison block.

Comment: You mentioned that you are trying to avoid the long version of a multi-value comparison block.  With the way your enum is defined, your short version just checks `if (val == 0 | 1 | 2)`, which can be simplified to `if (val == 3)`.  If you want to check `if (val == 0 || val == 1|| val == 2)`, you need to use the long version.

Comment: @BenJ that's the answer I was looking for.